# Python library for creating stubs/fake objects

Tags: python, testing, mocking, stub

I am looking for python stubbing library. Something that could be used to create fake classes/methods in my unit tests.. Is there a simple way to achieve it in python..

Thanks

PS: I am not looking for mocking library where you would record and replay expectation.

[Difference between mock and stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

Comment: "Mock objects always use behavior verification, a stub can go either way."  So a Stub is a Mock?  What's the point of saying "no mocks" when "stubs" can do the same thing as mocks?  Rather than quote a big article, please provide the actual difference that matters to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do this.

```
class FakeSomethingOrOther( object ):
   def __init__( self ):
       self._count_me= 0
   def method_required_by_test( self ):
       return self.special_answer_required_by_test
   def count_this_method( self, *args, *kw ):
       self._count_me += 1
```

It doesn't take much to set them up

```
class TestSomething( unittest.TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        self.requiredSomething = FakeSomethingOrOther()
        self.requiredSomething.attribute_required_by_test= 12
        self.requiredSomething.special_answer_required_by_test = 32
        self.to_be_tested = ActualThing( self.requiredSomething )
```

Since you don't require complex statically checked type declarations, all you need is a class with the right methods.  You can force test attribute values in trivially.

These things are really, really easy to write.  You don't need a lot of support or libraries.

In other languages (i.e., Java) it's very hard to write something that will pass muster with static compile-time checking.  Since Python doesn't have this problem, it's trivial to write mocks or fake implementations for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[Python mocker](http://labix.org/mocker) looks nice.

> A Mocker instance is used to command recording and replaying of
>   expectations on any number of mock objects.

Comment: Is it not a mocking framework... where you record expectation and verify them... is there nothing simpler that would just create fake implementation for me.. thanks

Comment: @StackUnderflow: You're splitting some kind of hair.  Can you update your question to define a difference between "mocking" and "fake implementation".  I think they're the same, but you're saying they're different.